# credentials used to authenticate does not have permission

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use firebase cloud messaging to deploy a http push notifications onto an actual device. When so, I am getting the error

"The credential used to authenticate this SDK does not have permission to send messages to the device corresponding to the provided registration token. Make sure the credential and registration token both belong to the same Firebase project."

I have checked the credentials on both the frontEnd and backEnd side and they all match up with my firebase correctly. I have tried to follow plenty of examples on here and I have missed on all of them. My node.js file looks like

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/Users/myname/mylocation/myfile.json"



exports.sendPushNotifications = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

 res.send("Attempting to send push notification")
 console.log("LOGGER --- Trying to send push message..");

 var uid = 'randomUIDString'

 var fcmToken = 'myToken'

 return admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid).once('value', snapshot => {

 var user = snapshot.val();

 console.log("username is " + user.name);

  var payload = {
  notification: {
  title: 'Push Notification Title',
  body: 'Test Notification Message'
  }
}

 admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload)
 .then(function(response) {
 console.log('Succesfully sent message:', response);
 console.log(response.results[0].error);

})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error sending message', error);
    });

  })
})
```

The users name prints from calling the uid, but I am having trouble accessing the fcmToken.
I have checked my info.plist and the correct project is listed. Same with apple developer and appDelegate. is there something more that I am missing??

Comment: You are having a [`mismatched-credential` error](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin). The recommendation is to make sure the credential and registration token both belong to the same Firebase project. See [Add Firebase to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#prerequisites) for documentation on how to authenticate the Firebase Admin SDKs.

Comment: @llompalles thanks for your reply. I have tried to restart the integration and follow it along and I am still getting the same issue. It may be the exports?? does that go in my appdel?

Comment: I have rechecked and my bundle ID matchs in xcode, firebase and appledeveloper